# Rand logic in modulo determination

Tags: python-3.x, random

So I want to know something, that seems simple but is mathematically stumping me in some code.

in the code block

```
import random
def randomGen(num):
    # Just a base prototype                                                     
    randVal = random.randrange(num)
    return randVal % 10

outputCount = [0 for x in range(10)] # Hold the count in                        
for i in range(1000000):
    myVal = str(randomGen(10))
#    print("Value " + myVal, end = '\t')                                        
    outputCount[int(myVal)]+=1

print(outputCount)
outputCount = [0 for x in range(10)] # Hold the count in                        
for i in range(1000000):
    myVal = str(randomGen(10000))
 #   print("Value " + myVal, end = '\t')                                        
    outputCount[int(myVal)]+=1

print(outputCount)
```

I understand that you are giving rand a much larger sample size, but does that actually increase the "randomness" of the value that you get from it, I ran the code a few times, not a million but a few, and statistically I feel as if it will always lead to roughly the same grouping. Like if you were to split a deck of cards in half, you'd attain roughly half the sum of the values on each side, if the deck had been shuffled in any order.

I'm unsure if this is just me being nitpicky, but I don't for some reason,  want to place an extensive "seed" in the value for rand because it seems unneeded, or is it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the statistics of random numbers.  Even at that, it is uhclear what you are asking.

Comment: As to the code, turning the int into a string just to turn it back into an int seems foolish.  Let print do the conversion if and when you print it.